# Mini Lyrics Alternative For Mac

Tags: itunes, music, lyrics

Have you guys seen the "mini lyrics" app for windows? It downloads the lyrics of the currently playing song and displays it on the screen. The great thing about it is that it highlights the current part of the lyrics. Do you know any alternative of it for mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Get Lyrical](http://shullian.com/get_lyrical.php)

I use this. It will display the lyrics and add them to your iTunes library (if you choose to) I would highly recommend it.

There is also [LessLyrics](http://ixhan.com/lesslyrics/). I haven't used it before.

Comment: Wow ! Thanx ! LessLyrics is exactly like minilyrics.

Comment: @AliBZ Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

## [Singer Song Reader](http://www.singer-song-reader.com/)

I used to be very happy with the OS X version of minilyrics, but recently, it stopped working on my machine (OS X El Capitan 10.11.2, Itunes 12.3.2.35).

What I really like with minilyrics was the ability of the app to find lyrics for almost every song, including for relatively obscur songs, and for songs in other languages than english.

I've tried Get Lyrical, Lesslyrics, and other options, but I was never satisfied by the breadth of songs these apps could find lyrics for.

This was until I found Singer Song Reader which gives me as much satisfaction (if not more) as minilyrics.

Answer (score 0):

The music app itself will display the lyrics if they are in the ID3 tags.  Get Lyrica or Apple Music or hand editing can put them there.